# Get the name of the content type from a page template

Tags: plone

I have a view for a folderish content type. I would like to leave out some fields based on which content type they are in. Is there a way to get the content type an object is from?

Comment: Do you have any template code yet? Have you seen the `Type` and `portal_type` attributes? `Type` is the type title, `portal_type` the type id.

Comment: No I hadn't, thanks, works great.  <div tal:content="item/portal_type"/>. Is there a place to see all the attributes?

Comment: I've always relied on reading the source code; I realize that that's not everyones cup of tea. It also depends on whether you are listing catalog results or full objects. The best I can find for you are http://developer.plone.org/content/types.html and http://developer.plone.org/content/listing.html.

Comment: since there is a lot of inheritance involved for archetypes objects, i often use http://plone.org/products/docfindertab to search for available methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All content types have a `portal_type` attribute (the type id as listed in the `portal_types` tool), as well as a `Type` attribute (the type title).

These are present even when listing content from the catalog.